# Motivation for defining filter convergence

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, filters, motivation

I've just learned about a filter converging in a topological space, but I just can't understand what's the motivation to define such a thing...

I get that it is a generalization of a sequence converging, but still, why?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I've found this great presentation which can answer my question:
http://www.math.tamu.edu/~wrobel/GIGEM2018/Talks/jgriffin-amsgigem.pdf

Answer (score 4):

It's not really inspired by sequence convergence, there is a generalisation of convergence in terms of [nets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) which *is* really inspired on that.

Both filters and nets offer a way to prove generalisations of well-known metric theorems about sequences, so that we can characterise continuity and closedness in terms of convergence notions that work in *all* spaces, not just ones with extra structure like metrics.

Filters are inspired on neighbourhood filters, in any space $X$ and for $x \in X$ we define the neighbourhood filter of $x$ as $$\mathcal{N}(x)= \{N \subseteq X: \exists O \subseteq X \text{ open }: x \in O \subseteq N\}$$

One can check that this obeys the filter axioms, and the idea is that $\mathcal{N}(x)$ should converge to $x$ (everything "close to" $x$ is in it).

The actual definition is simply that a filter $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $X$ converges to $x$, i.e. $\mathcal{F} \to x$ iff $\mathcal{N}(x) \subseteq \mathcal{F}$; anything larger than a filter converging to $x$ also converges to $x$ (superfilter roughly corresponds to the idea of subsequence, say).